# Elliptic regularity estimate with robin boundary condition in Yamabe problem on manifolds with boundary

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, elliptic-pde

I meet the following boundary problem in Escobar's Yamabe Problem On Manifolds With Boundary.https://projecteuclid.org/journals/journal-of-differential-geometry/volume-35/issue-1/The-Yamabe-problem-on-manifolds-with-boundary/10.4310/jdg/1214447805.pdf

$$
\begin{cases}\Delta u_\alpha-\frac{n-2}{4(n-1)} R u_\alpha+Q_\alpha(M) u_\alpha^\alpha=0 & \text { on } M \\ \frac{\partial u_\alpha}{\partial \eta}+\frac{n-2}{2} h u_\alpha=0 & \text { on } \partial M\end{cases}.
$$

Here $M$ is a compact manifold with boundary.$R$ is the scalar curvature of $(M,g)$.$h$ is mean curvature of $\partial M$.$\alpha\in(1,\frac{n+2}{n-2}).$

The formula comes from the following variational problem.
$$
Q_\alpha(\varphi)=\frac{E(\varphi)}{\left(\int_M|\varphi|^{\alpha+1} d v\right)^{2 / \alpha+1}}, \quad \varphi \in H_1(M)
$$

$$
E(\varphi)=\int_M\left(|\nabla \varphi|^2+\frac{n-2}{4(n-1)} R \varphi^2\right) d v+\frac{n-2}{2} \int_{\partial M} h \varphi^2 d \sigma.
$$

$$
Q_\alpha\left(M\right)=\min \left\{Q_\alpha(\varphi): \varphi \in H_1(M), \varphi \neq 0\right\}
$$

He says there exists a smooth $u_{\alpha}$ satisfying the equation.But he doesn't give the proof.

I have proved the existence of $H^{1}$weak solution and cannot improve the regularity of the weak solution.The weak solution has the following form.

$$
\int_M\left(\nabla \phi \cdot \nabla u_\alpha+\frac{n-2}{4(n-1)} R u_\alpha \phi-Q_\alpha(M) u_\alpha^\alpha \phi\right) d v+\frac{n-2}{2} \int_{\partial M} h u_\alpha \phi d \sigma=0
$$

In fact in Yamabe Problem on manifolds without boundary.We also study the regularity of
$$\Delta u_\alpha-\frac{n-2}{4(n-1)} R u_\alpha+Q_\alpha(M) u_\alpha^\alpha=0 \text { on } M.$$

In this case,classic elliptic regularity results work.

But I'm not quite familiar with elliptic regularity results with robin boundary condition.So I may just need some reference.

Any help will be thanked.

Comment: It's a bit hard to give a definitive answer because you don't explain what $R$ and $Q_\alpha$ are. That aside, are you saying that the classical elliptic regularity theory doesn't apply? This would seem like the first thing to try.

Comment: @LeoMoos Thank you for your comment.I'm not familiar with elliptic regularity with robin boundary condition.So I may just need some reference.And I will add the definition to make the question more clear.

Comment: Mmh, if you only want the solution to be smooth in the interior of your domain, I don't think the boundary condition ought to matter. Have you taken a look at the books of Gilbarg-Trudinger or Han-Lin? They are the standard references.